# What geared mechanisms can convert various weak stepper motors drive inputs into a higher torque output?

Tags: mechanism, gearing, stepper-driver, input, mechanical-engineering

I'm interested in making an arduino robotic arm for something that need precision and/or torque (like CNC), but first, I'm exploring/searching what I would need and how much it would cost.

What I intend to do is making its body as sturdy and solid as possible to minimise vibration, however, this means the body will become quite heavy.

But the heavy duty high-precision stepper motors are quite expensive (in my country's currency, of course), and if I need more than 3, it would cost too much for me.

I thought on using gear reduction to increase the the torque of a really small and cheap stepper motor, but I'm afraid it would be incredible slow. I'm not quite interested on super higher speeds, but something faster than a snail would be nice.

So I was wondering if there is **a mechanism that allows multiple drive inputs in a single axis to increase torque without too many reduction gears**.

[image]

Comment: are you asking about one gear being driven by multiple motors?

Comment: My sympathy for being low on funds -- been there, done that.  You may get more bang for your buck using DC motors and gearing them down.  Such motors certainly have more power for their _size_, but whether a DC motor + amplifier has more power for it's _cost_ is something you'll have to determine for yourself, based on what's available to you.

Comment: @jsotola any type of geared mechanism that allows for power amplification with multiple motors

Comment: Can you describe more about the application in the OP?  Are you trying to build a robot arm or something else?  You will need to consider what you want the arm to do - e.g. payload, speed, acceleration.